# Firebase deploy: Policy update access denied

Tags: function, vuejs2, firebase-tools

I have a Vue 2 proyect with firebase hosting and functions.

I am trying to create an authomatic deploy when I upload the code to github.

I have already firebase configuration done, but when I run:

```bash
firebase init hosting:github
```

Everything goes well until I select the repo.

This question:

```bash
? For which GitHub repository would you like to set up a GitHub workflow? (format: user/repository)
```

Returns me:

```bash
Error: HTTP Error: 403, Policy update access denied.
```

I am the `owner` of the repo and in firebase I have `editor` role.

I tried logout and login again but the problem still persist.

Comment: I have the same issue any solutions?